# Powershell Remote DIR Command Ouput to Remote Server

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I dont understand what is wrong. If I run this command in command prompt

```
dir /S/B | findstr "test" > \\server-name\c$\results.txt
```

It works fine. But If I try running it thru powershell on a remote computer

```
$result = ([WmiClass]"\\$s\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process").create("cmd /c dir /S/B | findstr ""test"" > \\server-name\c$\results.txt")
```

I have also tried

```
$result = ([WmiClass]"\\$s\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process").create("cmd /c dir /S/B | findstr ""test"" > \\192.168.1.100\c$\results.txt")
```

And I have tried created a log folder and sharing that out with full control for everyone

```
$result = ([WmiClass]"\\$s\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process").create("cmd /c dir /S/B | findstr ""test"" > \\192.168.1.100\log\results.txt")
```

None of this seems to work, but if I change it to a local path it works

```
$result = ([WmiClass]"\\$s\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process").create("cmd /c dir /S/B | findstr ""test"" > C:\results.txt")
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: what are the error messages or whatever that you get?

Comment: I dont get any error messages, that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all I am going to do is, after the command finishes move the file from the computer to the server.

```
    if(Test-path \\computer\c$\results.txt){
move-item -path \\computer\c$\results.txt \\server-name\c$ -force | out-host
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Psremoting on the machine and then use the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet to run remote command. I think that is more POSH way of doing it.

You can turn it on on many machines in your domain using Group Policy as well: http://blog.powershell.no/2010/03/04/enable-and-configure-windows-powershell-remoting-using-group-policy/

Comment: I am running this across the entire domain (on every single computer). And I can not turn things on or off.

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell you should escape the "-character using the backtick ` when used between "".

The following command worked on my system:

```
([WmiClass]"\\$s\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process").create("cmd /c dir /S/B | findstr `"test`" > \\192.168.1.100\c$\results.txt")
```

Comment: Is it possible that you can't write to the root of the C? Can you try `> \\192.168.1.100\c$\windows\temp\results.txt"`

Comment: I am running as DA, so I should have permissions. But I tried temp with no luck either. It must be a GPO thing?

Comment: try to run `cmd /c dir /S/B | findstr "test" > \\192.168.1.100\c$\results.txt` from an ordinary cmd box to eliminate that we're dealing with a permissions problem.

Comment: I logged into to the remote machine using same account. I then open command line as administrator and I typed the above command. And it worked.
See my dilemma and frustration?

Comment: This is probably a double-hop issue. Can you check if it works if `$s = "."` (which is what I used in my tests).